# Как изменить ImageButton с помощью DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialogfragment, android-button

Хочу сделать, чтобы при нажатии на `imageButton` открывается `DialogFragment` в котором мы нажимаем другой `ImageButton` (пускай будет 2). Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии 2ой кнопки на первую устанавливалось изображение со второй кнопки?

Код `DialogFragment`:

```
public class dlg1 extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {

    Button btnEur, btnUsd, btnRub, btnPl;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().setTitle("Выберите валюту");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
        v.findViewById(R.id.btnEur).setOnClickListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.btnUsd).setOnClickListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.btnRub).setOnClickListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.btnPl).setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnEur:
            dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }

    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить метод `newInstance()` в DialogFragment. Это общепринятый метод, используемый вместо обязательно пустого конструктора. Далее нужно получить [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) - объект для фрагмента, и добавить туда значение для фона первой кнопки. Останется только добавить Bundle к фрагменту. Код примерно такой:

```
public static dlg1 newInstance() {
    dlg1 fragment = new dlg1();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("любой таг" , 
             /*ссылка на ваше изображение в R.drawable*/);
    fragments.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragment;
}
```

Это надо вызывать вместо конструктора. Что бы "достать" изображение внутри кода, необходимо вызвать следующий метод:

```
savedInstanteState.get("любой таг");
```

P.S. А вообще не советую называть классы сокращениями. Например не dlg1, а CurrencyDialogFragment. Конечно, первая запись короче, но чем больше будет становиться проект, тем дольше вы будете вспоминать, что значит та или иная "аббревиатура".

Comment: По-другому сделал, просто установил кнопку staitc и обратился к ней из switch)
Может подскажешь где подробнее почитать о bundle или какой ресур хороший?)

Comment: Вообще, если нужна документация какая, заходи на Android Developers. Там все и про все есть. Вот ссылка, если что: www.developer.android.com .